# Link_to a page - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code:

```
<% slika = Refinery::Page.find('sladoledi') %>
<%= link_to (image_tag slika.key_image.url, slika) %>
```

The problem is that it's not linking to `slika`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start nesting code you write here. People have problem reading code like this :(

If you want add code click code button on editor.

I suppose the problem is you don't end image_tag.

Correct form is:

```
link_to(image_tag(slika.key_image.url),slika)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this format

```
 <%= link_to(slika) do %>
   <%= image_tag(slika.key_image.url)%>
 <% end %>
```

also have a look at documentation there are nice examples how to use link_to() helper

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to